# Independent Indexing in pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data with two indpendent indexes, say a date and an integer. Both determine unique rows. Now, I want to access rows by eather the date or the integer. This does not seem to work if I create the data frame via

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']], columns=['col1', 'col2'],
                  index=[[pd.to_datetime('2017-10-13'), pd.to_datetime('2017-10-14'), pd.to_datetime('2017-10-15')],
                         [123, 124, 125]])
```

since the indexes will be hierarchical. The data frame will be

```
               col1 col2
2017-10-13 123    a    b
2017-10-14 124    c    d
2017-10-15 125    e    f
```

With `.loc` I can access for example via date, say `df.loc['2017-10-13']` works nicely and as expected (actually even better since the string seems to be converted to `datetime` format automatically). Unfortunately, if I want to access a line via the integer index (for example with `df.loc[123]`) I get

```
KeyError: 'the label [123] is not in the [index]'
```

Does anyone know how to access lines via the integer index now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need tuples for seelct values in `MultiIndex`:

```
print (df.loc[('2017-10-13', 123)])
col1    a
col2    b
Name: (2017-10-13 00:00:00, 123), dtype: object
```

---

```
print (df.loc[('2017-10-13', 123),:])
               col1 col2
2017-10-13 123    a    b
```

If complicated select use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[idx['2017-10-13', 123]])
col1    a
col2    b
Name: (2017-10-13 00:00:00, 123), dtype: object

idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[idx['2017-10-13', 123],:])
               col1 col2
2017-10-13 123    a    b
```

---

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (df.loc[idx['2017-10-13', 123], 'col1'])
2017-10-13  123    a
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

EDIT:

Need function [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
print (df.xs(123, level=1))
           col1 col2
2017-10-13    a    b

print (df.xs(123, level=1, drop_level=False))
               col1 col2
2017-10-13 123    a    b
```

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately it doesn't help me because I want to access a line by just knowing the integer, but not the date.

Comment: Then is is simpliesr, give me a sec.

Comment: I totally forgot about `xs`. Well options deserve an upvote.

Comment: And your solution too ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do query by setting name to the index i.e

```
df.index.names=('a','b')
df.query('b==123')
```

Output :

```
             col1 col2
a          b            
2017-10-13 123    a    b
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I like solution of @jezrael a little bit more since I don't have to define names for my indexes.

Comment: Even I like his solution. He's pandas guru. Thats why I added an `also` in the answer.